# PHP, get values from an array?

Tags: php, json

I have a PHP key/value array and I want to grab a value from there and display it in a div.

So far I have:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/1389887261/reviews');
$parsed = json_decode($homepage);
```

I want to get the values out of the key/value pair array like this:

```
foreach ($parsed as $key => $values){
    echo $values['rating'];
}
```

But this does not retrieve the value.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the PHP foreach index reference, this gives you the ability to grab the key or the value.

```
$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
    echo $values['rating'];
}
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: i get `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array `

Comment: This is not correct.  `$parsed` is a stdClass object, not an array.

Comment: check freddy's answer, you'll need to provide true as the second argument in `$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);`. Updated my answer with it as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
$rating = $parsed->data[0]->rating;
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: i get  `Cannot use object of type stdClass as array `

Comment: @Patrioticcow I have modified my answer - the first version would work, if `json_decode()` would return associative array (which is not the case here).

Comment: @downvoter The reason you downvoted me is because it returned this error or something else?

Comment: removed the downvote when you corrected the factual error in the code sample (associative array vs stdClass) :)

Comment: @Chris Ok, thanks :) I apologize - I did not tested it before posting and did not find anything was wrong. But indeed there is no reason to get it as associative array.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
  echo $values['rating'];
}
```

**Note**, [json_decode()](http://php.net/json_decode) returns object by default. You need to update the following to do the above:

```
$parsed = json_decode($homepage, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

done by dumping your example)

```
foreach ($parsed->data as $key => $values){
echo $values->rating;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass the second parameter, you'll get back an object instead of an array, see http://php.net/json_decode

```
$parsed = json_decode($homepage,true);
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
    echo $values['rating'];
}
```

will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

The values are stdClass objects, not arrays.  So, to loop:

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/2345053339/reviews');
$parsed = json_decode($homepage);
foreach($parsed->data as $values) {
    echo 'Rating:'.$values->rating;
}
```

Note I am using the `->` operator to access object properties...

Answer (score -1):

Rating is a subarray of array ['data'], so:

```
foreach ($parsed['data'] as $key => $values){
    echo $values['rating'];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The root node for "parsed" is data which is an array so you probally want..

```
foreach($parsed['data'] as $key => $value) {
  echo $value['rating'];
}
```

Comment: This is not correct.  `$parsed` is a stdClass object, not an array.

Comment: @Chris, ease up on the downvotes. Most of these answers have updates.

Comment: The answers are totally wrong, non-functional code.  It's all well and good to flood a bunch of answers onto a question, if every single one of them is a duplicate of the other wrong answers, what is the utility in that?  Hence downvote.  This isn't a race or a contest - the idea is to factually answer a question.  Eh?